# Scaling of data before building model is necessary for all the models or not?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

Whether we need to scale(by zscale or by standardization) the data while building decision tree or random forests? As we know that we need to scale the data for KNN, K-means clustering and PCA. As these algorithms are based on distance calculations. What about scaling in Linear, Logistic, NavieBayes, Decision trees and Random forests?

Answer (score 2):

We do data scaling, when we are seeking for some relation between data point. In ANN and other data mining approaches we need to normalize the inputs, otherwise network will be ill-conditioned. We do the scaling to reach a linear, more robust relationship. Moreover, data scaling can also help you a lot to overcome outliers in the data. In short, data scaling is highly recommended in each type of machine learning algorithms.
You can do normalization or standardization in order to scale your data. 
[Notice that do not confuse normalization with standardization (e.g. Z-score)]
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Whether we need to scale(by zscale or by standardization) the data while building decision tree or random forests?

**A: Decision trees and Random Forests are immune to the feature magnitude and hence its not required.**

As we know that we need to scale the data for KNN, K-means clustering and PCA. As these algorithms are based on distance calculations. What about scaling in Linear, Logistic, NavieBayes, Decision trees and Random forests?

**A: In general, scaling is not an absolute requirement, its a recommendation, primarily for similarity based algorithms. For many algorithms, you may need to consider data transformation prior to normalization.There's also various normalization techniques you can try out, and there's no one size fits best for all problems. The main reason for normalization for error based algorithms such as linear, logistic regression, neural networks is faster convergence to the global minimum due to the better initialization of weights.Information based algorithms (Decision Trees, Random Forests) and probability based algorithms (Naive Bayes, Bayesian Networks) don't require normalization either.**

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is better to be done in general, because if all the features are on the same scale, the Gradient Descent Algorithm converges faster to the global or optimum local minimum.

We can speed up gradient descent by having each of our input values in roughly the same range. This is because our model parameters, will descend quickly on small ranges and slowly on large ranges, and so will oscillate inefficiently down to the optimum when the variables are very uneven.